# jetty Hello World Example not compiling

Tags: java, webserver, jetty, javac

I am trying to compile the java class on: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_HelloWorld

with Jetty web service.

For some reason when i try running:

`javac -cp servlet-api-2.5.jar:jetty-all-$JETTY_VERSION.jar HelloWorld.java`

It says there are 14, yes 14 errors:

```
C:\Users\n...\DEMO>javac -cp servlet-api-2.5.jar:jetty-all-
7.3.0.v20110203.jar HelloWorld.java HelloWorld.java:1: package javax.servlet.http does not exist import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
                         ^ HelloWorld.java:2: package javax.servlet.http does not exist import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
                         ^ HelloWorld.java:3: package javax.servlet does not exist import javax.servlet.ServletException;
                    ^ HelloWorld.java:7: package org.eclipse.jetty.server does not exist import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
                               ^ HelloWorld.java:8: package org.eclipse.jetty.server does not exist import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
                               ^ HelloWorld.java:9: package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler does not exist import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;
                                       ^ HelloWorld.java:11: cannot find symbol symbol: class AbstractHandler public class HelloWorld extends AbstractHandler
                                ^ HelloWorld.java:14: cannot find symbol symbol  : class Request location: class HelloWorld
                       Request baseRequest,
                       ^ HelloWorld.java:15: cannot find symbol symbol  : class HttpServletRequest location: class HelloWorld
                       HttpServletRequest request,
                       ^ HelloWorld.java:16: cannot find symbol symbol  : class HttpServletResponse location: class HelloWorld
                       HttpServletResponse response)
                       ^ HelloWorld.java:17: cannot find symbol symbol  : class ServletException location: class HelloWorld
        throws IOException, ServletException
                            ^ HelloWorld.java:20: cannot find symbol symbol  : variable HttpServletResponse location: class HelloWorld
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                           ^ HelloWorld.java:27: cannot find symbol symbol  : class Server location: class HelloWorld
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        ^ HelloWorld.java:27: cannot find symbol symbol  : class Server location: class HelloWorld
        Server server = new Server(8080);
                            ^ 14 errors
```

How do i fix it so it works on my machine, and i can complie and run it?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
HelloWorld.java (its on the site, but ill put it here):

`import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;

public class HelloWorld extends AbstractHandler
{
    public void handle(String target,
                       Request baseRequest,
                       HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
        response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.setHandler(new HelloWorld());

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}`

**UPDATE 2:**

In the process of installing JAVA EE SDK.
Will let you know if it works

Comment: Seeing the source code of HelloWorld.java would help...

Comment: Do you have the J2EE java installed, or just JDK?

Comment: ehhhh i think i have the jdk. how do i know about j2EE?

Comment: From here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html Get the bundle with Java EE.

Comment: ok im doing that now. ill let you know if that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, aren't you supposed to use ';' instead of ':' as a path separator?

Comment: THAT WORKED!  i guess they do the tutorial in linux and they dont tell u. thank you

Comment: That helped me out on a similar problem too. Thanks!

Comment: I know this is kinda spamming, but I get the same problem and this really helps me. Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 0):

i'd say you dont have the jar files in your current directory C:\Users\n...\DEMO

try:

javac -cp C\:*path\to*\servlet-api-2.5.jar:C\:*path\to*\jetty-all- 7.3.0.v20110203.jar HelloWorld.java

and replace the paths...

Comment: I do have both jars in the DEMO folder